# Request graphql with php

Tags: php, curl, graphql

I need to make a graphql query using pure php, is this possible and how to do it?

graphql request:

```
{
  getLastLowestProductPrices(
    lastLowestPricesInput: [{date: "2023-01-01", productId: 14397, sizeId: "uniw"}]
  ) {
    id
    sizes {
      id
      price {
        gross {
          value
          currency
        }
      }
    }
}
```

endpoint: `https://trening-dev1.iai-shop.com/graphql/v1/?docLang=pl`

Please help me

Edit:
my php code:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
        )
    );

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function get($endpoint)
{
    $json = '{
  getLastLowestProductPrices(
    lastLowestPricesInput: [{date: "2023-01-01", productId: 14397, sizeId: "uniw"}]
  ) {
    id
    sizes {
      id
      price {
        gross {
          value
          currency
        }
      }
    }
}';

    $result = do_post_request($endpoint, $json);
    print_r($result);
}

$endpoint = 'https://trening-dev1.iai-shop.com/graphql/v1/?docLang=pl';
get($endpoint);
```

Comment: You tagged this with `curl`, have you tried using it?

Comment: yes, I tried but it only returns me the default response hello: "null". The graphql code itself is good, but I can't adapt it to curl in php

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried then, instead of just _telling_ us that you tried "something".

Comment: @CBroe sorry, added my code to first post

Comment: Does your endpoint not need any authorization? Or is this missing an `Authorization: Bearer ...` header?

Comment: `$json = '...'` - that's not actually valid JSON what you got there.

Comment: @CBroe I got this screenshot from the developers [link](https://ibb.co/MCxX2T5)